# Structure and form of the ketubah

Tags: halacha, marriage, ketubah

Where can I find a list of requirements for a ketubah (what it needs say, how it needs to be phrased, and - most importantly - what invalidates it from being a kosher ketubah)?

Comment: _Even Haezer_ 66–118. `:-)`

Comment: Thanks, @msh210. I've just looked through those chapters (fairly cursorily, I might add), but did not find anywhere that the mechaber mentions the actual language of the ketubah, and the usage of translations into the vernacular. Is that mentioned anywhere in Even haEzer?

Comment: Translations into the vernacular? Where did that come from? If you'd like a sourced answer as to whether non-Aramaic _k'suvos_ are okay (or can be used _l'chat'chila_) then I suggest you [ask that](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377.

Comment: Sorry, @msh210 - I didn't mean that as it sounded. I am referring to ketubot that feature translations together with the Aramaic. But that's not my major question: what I want is a comprehensive list of everything that would nullify a ketubah, and I note that this is something not (apparently) mentioned in Even haEzer.

Comment: You might want to also inquire at the [Ketubah Artists' Association](http://www.ketubahaa.org) - they're the experts on these types of questions!

Answer (score 2):

[Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/477326/jewish/The-Ketubah.htm) have an article on what the ketubah says.

> The focal point of the document is the financial compensation due to
>   the wife in the event of the marriage's dissolution through divorce or
>   widowhood. The ketubah even includes provisions which place liens on
>   the husband's different assets.
>
> When a Jewish man marries a Jewish woman he automatically obligates
>   himself to his wife in ten areas; some are Torah mandated and others
>   by rabbinic decree. A number of these obligations are mentioned
>   specifically in the ketubah and others are implied:  He must 1) feed
>   his wife; 2) clothe her; and 3) provide her conjugal needs. His estate
>   is obligated to 4) pay her a lump sum in the event that he divorces
>   her or dies before she does. He must 5) pay her medical bills if she
>   falls ill; and 6) ransom her if she is taken hostage. If the wife
>   passes away before the husband, he must 7) pay her burial expenses,
>   and 8) after he dies, her children inherit their mother's ketubah
>   money before the rest of the estate is divided amongst all the heirs.
>   In the event that the husband dies before the wife, 9) she is entitled
>   to live in his home and live off his estate until she dies or
>   remarries, and 10) her daughters, too, are supported by his estate
>   until they marry.
>
> Today, the standard ketubah is a printed form which has blanks for the
>   date and the names of the bride, groom, and witnesses.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketubah#References) references a “text of a prenuptial agreement” = ketubah at http://www.rabbis.org/ endorsed by the Rabbinical Council of America. (There is a link on the right hand side of the page under “Commonly Used Forms”).

[Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/532557/jewish/Ketubah.htm) have a text too – follow the link.